# How to ignore extra spaces in LDAP filter

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap

My filter looks something like this

```
&(extensionAttribute2=123456)
```

I can foresee instances where the values might have spaces at the beginning or end of the string and I don't want to exclude those. I realize I could use wild cards to match like so

```
&(extensionAttribute2=*123456*)
```

But that will match more than just spaces, and I don't want to do that. Is there some kind of "white space only" wild card I could use, or some other approach I haven't thought of?